# How to implement spark.ui.filter

Tags: apache-spark, servlet-filters

I have a spark cluster set up on 2 CentOS machines. I want to secure the web UI of my cluster (master node). I have made a BasicAuthenticationFilter servlet. I am unable to understand:

1. how should I use spark.ui.filter to secure my web UI.
2. Where should I place the servlet/jar file.

Kindly help.

Comment: You can ask this question in stack exchange for batter response

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to handle this security problem to prevent unauthorized access to spark standalone UI. At last I fixed it after surfing on the web, the procedure is :

1. code and compile a java filter using standard basic authentication protocol, I refered to this [blog]: http://lambda.fortytools.com/post/26977061125/servlet-filter-for-http-basic-auth
2. packaged above filter class as a jar file, put it in $spark_home/jars/
3. add config lines in $spark_home/conf/spark-default.conf as :

   - spark.ui.filters        xxx.BasicAuthFilter # the full class name
   - spark.test.BasicAuthFilter.params       user=foo,password=cool,realm=some

     the username and password need to provide to access the spark UI, “realm” is insignificant whatever you typed
4. restart all slave and master process and test to find it works

Answer (score -2):

Hi place the jar file in all the nodes in the folder `/opt/spark/conf/`. In terminal, type the following commands:

- Navigate to the directory `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json`
- Edit the file kernel.json
- Add the following argument to the PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS `--jars /opt/spark/conf/filterauth.jar –conf spark.ui.filters=authenticate.MyFilter`

Here, filterauth.jar is the jar file created and authenticate.MyFilter represents `<package name>.<class name>`

Hope this answers your query. :)